# Redirect to ActionResult Method in the same controller - Authorization header is missing - ERROR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download, antiforgerytoken, redirecttoaction

I am trying to redirect from a controller action (using `RedirectToAction()`) to another action in the same controller.

The website is using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, and I get the error in the request:

> Authorization header is missing

I haven't set `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` on that method, and don't really need forgery checking for this one.

Does anyone know how should I proceed?

The actual behavior is that from a method, I redirect to another which is trying to download an excel file.

Thanks.

Comment: What type of authentication are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using redirect ? If you just want the output of another method, you can simple call

```
ActionResult MyOriginalMethod()
{
  ...
  return AnotherControllerMethod(parameter);
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
ActionResult MyOriginalMethod()
{
  ...
  return RedirectToAction("AnotherControllerMethod");
  ...
}
```

the later actually performs http redirect, which is a) slower b) you have to set context properly.